# need a diode to put in when installing new wiring

Tags: wiring, part-identification, harley-davidson

need a diode for a Harley  three wheel police bike. don't know any specs but is a 12 volt alternator system. diode goes between gen. and oil press. lights and the regulator. Harley no. 74559-65 is not to be found any where. please help.

Comment: what happened to your diode? can you show a photo to describe size

Comment: not there when I got bike. it needed rewiring

Comment: have you actually done any research on the internet? ... it shows up as a resistor/diode assembly and appears to be available

Comment: any company name you can share with me?

Comment: Active electronics, Future electronics, Digikey, Mouser , all have 'em  many brands.. check local parts stores 1N4004  Diodes Inc  400V

Comment: Can you show a wiring diagram or a pic of the wiring around the diode?

Answer (score 2):

just about any diode to handle the load current of accessory.

### Update

Source found shows Diode and R in a sleeve.  https://www.vintageindian.com/harley-1905-to-1966/servi-car-1932-to-1973/1965-to-1970-ge-harley-servi-car-74559-65-resistor/diode-assembly.html

[image: schematic]

[image: schematic]

Comment: a 2 cylinder scooter

Comment: Ah...I guess I should have been more imaginative.

Comment: "*Some of us take the bike to work, some others take some darlington transistors, lamps, diodes, gates and transformer to work... engineers are magical creatures*"

Comment: You have some nails in your tires...

Comment: studded tires for winter. This is cool. I figured out how to watch 3 Olympic channels simultaneously on my big screen from the computer

Comment: But if they're Darlington *pairs*, does that make it a 4-wheeler?

Comment: or dual shoe drum brakes

Comment: It's not all too clear to me exactly where the diode is placed and what it does, but isn't it too easy too immediately assume it's just a generic one? I recently had to replace one in my car that had to be a specific zener diode.

Comment: You are correct.  The condition it must satisfy is the load current, which we do not know.  But if you know the alternator is rated for 50A , then it may be possible you need a 50A diode.  I am not sure of it's purpose because car alternators use 6 diodes in a 3 phase bridge.  Often incase or battery boost or open circuit on battery under load, you get a large reverse voltage spike and this will block Peak Inverse voltages of 400V for x=4  So the wire gauge (ampacity) will give me a clue if you can measure its conductor diameter.  RSVP

Comment: I found a source for the part and it describes it as a Resistor Diode in a plastic sleeve, so it does not appear to be a high current ( power, heat) part and must be regulated somewhere. If you have  the schematics in the Harley Davidson 1966-1984 Shovelheads Clymer Service Manual, it may indicate the R value and diode clues